# VB 2010/2012 Project Creation Error

Tags: vb.net

`Access to the path "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\svuqua0k.ydm\Form.vb" is
denied`

I've been creating projects, Adding items through it but it just started this a few days ago, I don't know why...

Happens with `C++`, `VB`, `C#`
When creating a project
And
When adding a item.

I tried answer #1 but it didn't work, Also i couldn't respond to him for some reason.

Egh, i fixed it, i had to un-install it 3 times tho.. so total of 4 installs trying to fix this..

Comment: Have you changed permissions on any folder/subfolder in the path?

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting the IDE

Then delete the contents of

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\
```